# Clean-up of exceptions declared in interface but not thrown by implementation

Tags: java, exception, interface

I have a lot of Java interfaces with only one main implementation (not counting mocks and stubs).

Over time, the interface and its implementation evolve, including the exceptions that are thrown by some methods.

The problem is that when we add an exception in the implementation, the compiler reminds us to add the exception on the interface. But when an exception is not thrown anymore by the implementation, there is a warning reminding us to remove the exception declaration on the implementation, but we often forget to remove it from the interface.

And so we end up, in the client code of the interface, dealing with exceptions that are never actually thrown.

Step 1, we have an exception in the implementation, it is propagated up the chain:

```
interface Service {
    void doSomething() throws MyException;
}
class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    void doSomething() throws MyException {
        if (dummyCondition) {
            throw new MyException("oops");
        }
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
class Client {
    @Inject Service service;
    void clientCode() {
        try {
            service.doSomething();
        } catch(MyException e) {
            logger.error("oops", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2, the exception is not thrown anymore by the implementation, but we forgot to clean the interface, and so don't realize the catch is not useful anymore:

```
interface Service {
    void doSomething() throws MyException;
}
class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    void doSomething() {
        if (dummyCondition) {
            logger.warning("actually, don't throw, just log 'oops'");
        }
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
class Client {
    @Inject Service service;
    void clientCode() {
        try {
            service.doSomething();
        } catch(MyException e) {
            logger.error("oops", e); // we'll never get there.
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like a warning on the interface saying something like "Exception declared but not thrown by any known implementation".

Is there a way to detect those declared-but-never-thrown exceptions, in Eclipse or with a source code analysis tool, to be able to do some clean-up ?

Comment: When you do an API that will be used by external clients it is a good practice to declare all the Exceptions as RuntimeException.

Comment: Should you be implementing an interface, instead of updating the interface as a result of change in implementation ?

Comment: It's not meant to be used by external clients. It's only internal to my project. I'm declaring an interface to make it easier to test clients of the interface (which are other classes within the same product) without testing the implementation code at the same time

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) {
            System.out.println("Thread "+arg0+" throwed uncaught exception:");
            arg1.printStackTrace();


            cleanupcode(); //clean up code
            savefiles(); //method to save files used by your app
            //You can create here a dialog with crash:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread "+arg0+" throwed uncaught exception: "+arg1);
            System.exit(0);
        }});
```

???

Comment: Not really. I'm talking about exceptions declared in interfaces, but not thrown by any implementation. It's a code clean-up problem, not something to deal with at runtime

Comment: Write sample. I don't understand